# Black images from canvas.toDataURL()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asynchronous, canvas

I have created a web application where users can upload images from their filesystem but in few cases I only get black image data on the server side. I have never got this issue in my development environment on lan even with the original images causing the error. This failure occurs overall only sporadic but especially one user is affected. All users should work with the latest firefox. I have read most of the question about this topic and I dont think this is related to a security issue, the jpg/png setting or preserveDrawingBuffer. Because I have never got this problem on lan with a fast PC and the fact that often the last selected images are affected it seems to be a synchronization problem.
To avoid this I work with $.Deferred and Callbacks but may be I missed something. First I load and convert the selected images directly into a list of canvas. The upload is disabled until this is finished. During the upload I just loop through the canvas list and read the data (canvas.toDataURL()) with a $.Deferred and transfer it to the server via ajax.

Get the images to the page:

```
var file = document.getElementById('fileSelect');
if (file != undefined) {
file.onchange = function (e) {
    btnUpload.SetEnabled(false);
    loadImgs(e, function () {
        btnUpload.SetEnabled(true);
    });
};
}

function loadImgs(e, callback) {

for (var t = 0; t < e.target.files.length; t++) {
    if ($('.CanvasClass').length <= 20) {

        var myTmpImg = new Image();
        var myName = e.target.files[t].name;
        myTmpImg.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[t]);
        myTmpImg.onload = function () {

            var GrenzeX = 1024;
            var GrenzeY = 768;
            var myFactor = 1;
            if (myTmpImg.naturalWidth > GrenzeX || myTmpImg.naturalHeight > GrenzeY) {
                if ((GrenzeX / myTmpImg.naturalWidth) < (GrenzeY / myTmpImg.naturalHeight)) {
                    myFactor = GrenzeX / myTmpImg.naturalWidth;
                } else {
                    myFactor = GrenzeY / myTmpImg.naturalHeight;
                }
            }

            var myCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            myCanvas.className = "CanvasClass";
            myCanvas.height = this.naturalHeight * myFactor;
            myCanvas.width = this.naturalWidth * myFactor;

            var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
            $("#myImages").append(myCanvas);

            myMetaData.push(new newImgData('', '', myName));
        }

    }
}
if (callback && typeof callback == "function") {
    callback();
}

}
```

Read and transfer the Data:

```
$('.CanvasClass').each(function () {
var fd = new FormData();
var base64Data = getBase64Image(this, false);
base64Data.then(function (result) {
    //Create Ajax Request         
});
});

function getBase64Image(myCanvas, modus) {
var deferred = $.Deferred();
var dataURL = myCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.9);
if (modus === true) {
    deferred.resolve(dataURL);
} else {
    deferred.resolve(dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg);base64,/, ""));
}
return deferred.promise();
}
```

I can also exclude issues during the data transfer because I logged the size of the images on clientside before uploading and compared this to the data at  serverside and it was the same.

Comment: If you're not doing anything to these images, why don't you send it directly ? Passing it to a canvas means decompressing, then convert to bitmap (keeps jpeg artifacts) then recompressing (more jpeg artifacts) with the poor default JPEG compression your browser offers you (heavier than original or with more artifacts) + b64 encoding (+30% heavier).

Comment: For your problem, since it may be interesting to solve it anyway, it's only one image in the batch ? Otherwise, your client may have some extension which blocks canvas extract methods (to protect against fingerprinting). Also, are you sure all images were correct (your user could have passed a .tiff or a broken file.)

Comment: @ Kaiido As you can see I scale down the resolution of the images and I also make sure that everything is jpeg before uploading. Furthermore the users are also able to edit the pictures. It can be up to 20 images in the list. This cant be a general problem because even the user I mentioned is able to send some of these correctly.

Comment: Sorry somehow missed the resize part... But I still don't see where nor how you check the validity of the original image. You don't seem to listen for onerror.  Personnaly I would still go with canvas.toBlob for the upload. Also, even if unrelated to your issue, I doubt your max count check will work. $(class) will grab only the canvases already present in the document, which are appended only at the images load (would be a problem only of someone do upload more than one file at a time)

Comment: The count validation works no matter how many files you select. The problem is also not connected the images. If I upload the same "problem-images" on lan it works as expected.

Comment: No it doesn't work https://jsfiddle.net/dpsrv5m0/ but it doesn't matter with your problem. Also, `toDataURL` is synnchronous so your deferred should be useless here.